# Node,Express, Angular routing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm learning the MEAN stack but for now have not started with the db. I tried to wire the rest of the stack but it throws an error

> Error: Access to restricted URI denied createHttpBackend

I googled and could not find any solutions to this problem.

This is my main controller in Angular app.js:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("success");
    $http.get('/').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("success");
        $scope.name = data.name;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.name = 'Error!';
    })
});
```

My node server app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var name = 'MyNameFromServer';
    res.send(name);
})

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

And this is the error in browser console ( when Angular http.get happens):

```
"Error: Access to restricted URI denied
createHttpBackend/<@file:///F:/routing/js/angular.js:9902:6
sendReq@file:///F:/routing/js/angular.js:9703:0
$http/serverRequest@file:///F:/routing/js/angular.js:9415:15
```

Please help me out.

**This is the full app** - https://github.com/V1cHu/routing

Comment: try to some other url instead of "/"

Comment: Which part of the stack is throwing this error? I can't tell if it's the node app throwing this in bash or angular in the browser console

Comment: angular throws in browser console.

Comment: @Mohit acutally when I try to hit the link localhost:3000/ , node console shows the GET hit , but when I try this using the angular app , it does not hit the node server at all

Comment: Try `$http.get('http://localhost:3000/')` instead of `$http.get('/')`

Comment: @JoaoLeal tried that,. Now browser console throws "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)." . The node console does not indicate a hit..

Comment: So now you just need to fix the CORS error https://gist.github.com/dirkk0/5967221

Comment: Still get the CORS error!

Comment: In my setup I don't have http in the server at all, only using `method-override` middleware: `app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));`

Comment: this is the full app - https://github.com/V1cHu/routing

Comment: I ran your code and It is working

Comment: @Mohit u mean you got the response from the node server ?? are u sure ? How exactly did you run the code ?

Comment: yeah localhost:3000/ is showing only the response MyNameFromServer not with complete html on browser because angular is not getting initialzed

Comment: My requirement is to get it to work in the browser through angular.. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing your code,I found there are few problems in your code 
1) You **don't** need to add that crossbrowser support code

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST","PUT");
 next()}
);
```

and also this code

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

2) In the server side app.js file change the call app.get('/') to some other route for eg   app.get('/xyz') because it does not allow you to load  your angular js code

3)In your main controller (MainCtrl) use $http.get('/xyz') as updated above.**Don't** use  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/')

```
$http.get('/xyz').
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("success");
    $scope.name = data;
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.name = 'Error!';
})
```

EDIT: in server side app.js add this code

```
var path = require('path')
app.use(express.static(path.normalize(__dirname + '/')));
```

and in the client  side app.js file change $scope.name to data **not data.name**

```
  $scope.name = data;
```

It will solve issues in your problem

Comment: I tried each and every step of yours. It still doesn't work. I get "Access to restricted URI error" now.

Comment: I have checked your code on my machine.It is working fine

Comment: Please run this code at this [link](https://github.com/mohit181191/routing).This has been forked from your repo and works perfectly on my machine

Comment: I ran your code, still it does not work for me. It throws the same error. Please let me know how exactly do you run the code ? I start the node server and then open index.html in my browser.

Comment: go into your directory and type "node app" in the command prompt.and then run localhost:3000 in the browser.You don't need to open index.html by your self

Comment: Sorry for being so stupid. The code works .. Thank you so much man ! :)

Comment: Please help me understand. How does index.html open when I hit localhost:3000 . I have not specified anywhere to open index.html when the path is '/' ???

Comment: Also the server console does not show a GET hit when I run the app. Why is that now registering ?

Comment: var path = require('path')
app.use(express.static(path.normalize(__dirname + '/')));This code always looks up for static files and if any particular html in not defined it uses index.html as default.

Comment: Is that a hack or a best practice ?

Comment: It is a best practice.Not a hack.Hope it solves all your problems.Please accept and vote up my answer

Comment: Thanks for you help and clarifications :)